# ModelMetaData: How to get "Parent"-Metadata?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

In my view I call Html.EditFor() which triggers a custom editor-template for this datatype. Additionally I pass some Metadata with it (and that's the part I don't like):

```
<% ModelMetadata metaTitle = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForProperty(null, Model.GetType(), "Title"); %>
<%: Html.EditorFor(x => Model.Title, new { metaData = metaTitle })%>
```

The passed type (property Title) is of type 'Translation'. Within the custom editor-template I have to read the passed metadata from the viewData in order to use it:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Translation>" %>
// {...}
if (ViewData["metaData"] != null)
    metaData = (ModelMetadata)ViewData["metaData"];
```

Is there some way I could access the metadata directly within the custom editor-template? Unfortunately, if I call the following within the editor-template, I won't get the same metadata-object (where for example the information if the Title-Property is required or not is missing):

```
ModelMetadata metaData = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, Model.GetType());
```

I would like to avoid to pass the metadata-object on each call...

Thx for any tipps!
sl3dg3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're trying to get the metadata for the actual property for the EditorTemplate.

You can do this like this (inside the EditorTemplate):

```
var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromStringExpression("", ViewData);
```

"" means for MVC the current property.

Comment: You are absolutely right, that was what I was looking for - finally I could verify it.

Comment: +1 - Nice find...the API for this is very powerful but unintuitive.

Answer (score 5):

You could try the following to access the parent metadata:

```
<%
    var parentType = this.ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerType;
    var metadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, parentType);
%>
```

Comment: Good point - but now I have the metadata of the parent viewModel (okay, my title was maybe missleading). But I would like to have the metadata of `ParentModel.Title` - only problem here is that I don't know the name of the property within the editor template...

Comment: @sl3dg3, if you don't know the name of the property inside the editor template how do you expect to get its value?

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly a little late to the party, however there is a simpler way to get the model metadata for the current model - it exists as a [property of ViewData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewdatadictionary.modelmetadata%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

```
var metadata = ViewData.ModelMetadata;
```