# Get another property's value from ModelMetaData

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to get to another property's value from within the `GetClientValidationRules` method of a custom validation attribute.

Here is my attempt (based on [Darin's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089086/modelmetadata-how-to-get-parent-metadata) on another question):

```
public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(
    ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
{
    var parentType = metadata.ContainerType;
    var parentMetaData = ModelMetadataProviders.Current
        .GetMetadataForType(null, parentType);

    var parentMetaData = ModelMetadataProviders.Current
        .GetMetadataForProperties(context.Controller.ViewData.Model, parentType); 

    var otherProperty = parentMetaData.FirstOrDefault(p => 
        p.PropertyName == "SomeProperty");

    var otherValue = otherProperty.Model;

    var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
    {
        ValidationType = "customvalidatorattribute",
        ErrorMessage = this.FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),
    };

    yield return rule;
}
```

However, when trying to set `otherValue`, I get:

> System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.

Comment: how you got this thing resolved. I am having same issue, any suggestions?

Comment: hi by any chance you solve this problem please? I am having the same issue please?

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you are not passing in the bound model.  Change the following two lines:

```
var parentMetaData = ModelMetadataProviders.Current
    .GetMetadataForProperties(context.Controller.ViewData.Model, parentType); 
var otherValue = (string)parentMetaData.FirstOrDefault(p => 
    p.PropertyName == "SomeProperty").Model;
```

This will get the full metadata (including the bound values) from the current model.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still having issues.  See my updated example in my OP -- where it's setting `var otherValue = otherProperty.Model;`, I'm getting "System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.".

Comment: The problem with that line is that `var` is for implicit types, which does not include objects.  Change the line to `var otherValue = otherProperty.Model.ToString();`

Comment: No, the error is getting thrown when evaluating `otherProperty.Model` -- so it's failing before I could even do `ToString()`.

Answer (score 2):

@JeradRose, the problem with your TargetException is because of this line:

```
var parentMetaData = ModelMetadataProviders.Current
    .GetMetadataForProperties(context.Controller.ViewData.Model, parentType);
```

parentType needs to be `context.Controller.ViewData.Model.GetType()`.

Probably you already fixed it, but I just got it today.